# Xcode 4.6.3 Crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode4.6.3

Xcode 4.6.3 is crashing after stop scrolling editor like stuck on one place then i can not scroll up an down my code file (.m). Logs are as follows.

```
Process:         Xcode [740]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.6.3 (2068)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-2068000000000000~3
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [150]
Responsible:     Xcode [740]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-11-11 12:05:35.745 +0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  46CCFF4C-8447-75AD-4DA4-9CA79FE8B0A1

Sleep/Wake UUID: 35DF1E2F-BE42-435F-8E17-A1844E2F4737

Crashed Thread:  6  Dispatch queue: Garbage Collection Work Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000017

VM Regions Near 0x17:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001042b9000-00000001042bc000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H1503
objc[740]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83389b16 syscall_thread_switch + 10
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff8aca1df6 _OSSpinLockLockSlow + 63
2   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3b41cb auto_read_weak_reference + 235
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff873e0485 __35-[NSWindow _postInvalidCursorRects]_block_invoke + 26
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff880520a7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88052017 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff880437b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff81368f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff81368cb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff81368abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86c6728e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86c668db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86c5a9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86c45803 NSApplicationMain + 940
15  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x00000001042bab6f 0x1042b9000 + 7023
16  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x00000001042bab00 0x1042b9000 + 6912

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338e662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8423343d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff84233152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338de6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba5f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338de6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba5f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83389a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83388d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88044315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88be5907 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88be570b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338de6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba5f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: Garbage Collection Work Queue
0   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3c19a0 void Auto::Admin::visit_purgeable_nodes<Auto::PurgingVisitor>(Auto::PurgingVisitor&) + 96
1   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3bf558 Auto::Admin::purge_free_space_no_lock() + 24
2   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3c802f Auto::Zone::purge_free_space() + 271
3   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3c7dc3 Auto::Zone::collect(bool, void*, Auto::CollectionTimer&) + 547
4   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3b5b19 auto_collect_internal(Auto::Zone*, unsigned int) + 377
5   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3b115d __auto_zone_collect_block_invoke + 77
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff842341d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff842312ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8423368f _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff842349dd _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff84232fa3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff84234193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba5ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338de6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba5f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83389a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83388d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88044315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x000000010c9d67a3 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 229
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88be570b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8808fd43 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba6c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8b35ca38 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 656
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8b35c78f startIOThread(void*) + 147
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83389a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83388d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88044315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86e071ce _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83389a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83388d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88044315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88be7a7c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88cd070a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88be570b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338de6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba5f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba6c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001088f27e4 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 457
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88be570b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: <lldb.comm.debugger.input>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011568739a lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 374
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115686fe1 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 151
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115685826 lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 98
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115685482 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 174
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156f52b2 ThreadCreateTrampoline(void*) + 108
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:: <lldb.comm.xcode.lldb.comm>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011568739a lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 374
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115686fe1 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 151
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115685826 lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 98
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115685482 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 174
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156f52b2 ThreadCreateTrampoline(void*) + 108
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: <lldb.process.gdb-remote.async>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011568739a lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 374
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115686fe1 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 151
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115684f06 lldb_private::Communication::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 246
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115730283 GDBRemoteCommunication::WaitForPacketWithTimeoutMicroSecondsNoLock(StringExtractorGDBRemote&, unsigned int) + 179
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001157d9750 GDBRemoteCommunicationClient::SendContinuePacketAndWaitForResponse(ProcessGDBRemote*, char const*, unsigned long, StringExtractorGDBRemote&) + 550
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011573a4a2 ProcessGDBRemote::AsyncThread(void*) + 538
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156f52b2 ThreadCreateTrampoline(void*) + 108
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=0)>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba6c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156f4cf5 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011569a9b9 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 93
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011569b83c lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 324
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011569b9f9 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001157a3331 lldb_private::Process::WaitForEventsPrivate(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&, bool) + 123
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001157a8785 lldb_private::Process::RunPrivateStateThread() + 221
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001157a83cf lldb_private::Process::PrivateStateThread(void*) + 9
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156f52b2 ThreadCreateTrampoline(void*) + 108
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83389a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83388d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88044315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88043275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff880f89d1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff81efb7e3 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 355
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: <lldb session listener>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8338d716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba6c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156f4cf5 lldb_private::Condition::Wait(lldb_private::Mutex&, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 109
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011569a9b9 lldb_private::Predicate<bool>::WaitForValueEqualTo(bool, lldb_private::TimeValue const*, bool*) + 93
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011569b83c lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEventsInternal(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, lldb_private::Broadcaster*, lldb_private::ConstString const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 324
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011569b9f9 lldb_private::Listener::WaitForEvent(lldb_private::TimeValue const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Event>&) + 27
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000114959cb3 lldb::SBListener::WaitForEvent(unsigned int, lldb::SBEvent&) + 209
7   com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x000000010bec2242 DBGLLDBSessionThread(void*) + 722
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156f52b2 ThreadCreateTrampoline(void*) + 108
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba4899 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba472a _pthread_start + 137
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 21:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis.PerfLogging.WSUpdateHandling_queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff83389b16 syscall_thread_switch + 10
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff8aca1df6 _OSSpinLockLockSlow + 63
2   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3b9ca8 void Auto::Zone::set_write_barrier<Auto::SubzoneBlockRef, Auto::SubzoneBlockRef>(Auto::Thread&, Auto::SubzoneBlockRef, void const**, Auto::SubzoneBlockRef, void const*) + 120
3   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3b9b0d void set_write_barrier_dest_sieve<Auto::SubzoneBlockRef>::processBlock<Auto::SubzoneBlockRef>(Auto::SubzoneBlockRef) + 349
4   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3b8b44 void Auto::sieve_base::sieve_base_pointer<set_write_barrier_value_sieve>(Auto::Zone*, void const*, set_write_barrier_value_sieve&) + 260
5   libauto.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3b2637 auto_zone_set_write_barrier + 39
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff84adf02c objc_assign_strongCast_gc(objc_object*, objc_object**) + 28
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe27e4 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 740
8   com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis   0x00007fff89bdda66 -[PAPerfLoggingOperation markIntervalTransition:transitionType:atCGSTimestampInSec:withContext:] + 120
9   com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis   0x00007fff89bcb176 PAPerfLoggingProcessWSUpdateInfoDictionary + 1137
10  com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis   0x00007fff89bd2fa1 gWSUpdateHandler_block_invoke_2 + 179
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff842341d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff842312ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8423368f _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff842349dd _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff84232fa3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff84234193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba5ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff87ba8fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0xffffffffffffffff  rbx: 0x401a7d7fffffe000  rcx: 0x00007fff8338e722  rdx: 0xffffffffffffffff
  rdi: 0x000000000000000c  rsi: 0x401a7d7fffffe000  rbp: 0x0000000109b9eba0  rsp: 0x0000000109b9eb60
   r8: 0x0000000000000010   r9: 0xffffffffffffffff  r10: 0x000000010603a470  r11: 0x0000000000000207
  r12: 0xffffffffffffffff  r13: 0x0000000000003000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000109b9ebb0
  rip: 0x00007fff8b3c19a0  rfl: 0x0000000000010213  cr2: 0x0000000000000017

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 475
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=324.5M resident=195.2M(60%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=129.3M(40%)
Writable regions: Total=17.5G written=209.4M(1%) resident=348.5M(2%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=17.1G(98%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
CG backing stores                    7128K
CG image                              132K
CG raster data                       18.1M
CG shared images                      172K
CoreAnimation                         328K
CoreData                                4K
CoreImage                              24K
Foundation                             12K
IOKit                                15.9M
Image IO                              152K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              647.4M
MALLOC (admin)                         48K
MALLOC (reserved)                    15.8G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                         40K
OpenCL                                 44K
OpenGL GLSL                          1664K
SQLite page cache                    18.0M
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                17.8M
VM_ALLOCATE                          16.5M
WebKit Malloc                        1232K
__DATA                               41.5M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           85.8M
__TEXT                              238.7M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                         238.6M
shared memory                          68K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                18.1G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space        1.4G


Model: Macmini6,2, BootROM MM61.0106.B03, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.8f1
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3431554638424455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3431554638424455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x10E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662, 1 TB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: If you always have this problem you should file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com. You could also update Xcode.

Comment: I am getting very similar results. Where I work we are still developing and maintaining some apps for iOS 6 and thus use Xcode 4. I have both Xcode 5 and Xcode 4 installed. Xcode 4 on OS 10.9 will run for a while and then crash when trying to access a specific. My other colleagues both use Xcode 5 and Xcode 4 and don't experience this. They seem to think I'm crazy, :( ....